# What does 'revert unchanged files' mean in Perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

What does the command 'revert unchanged files' do in Perforce? It sounds like a contradiction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have files checked out in perforce, but not have made any changes to them.  They will still show up in your changesets.  Revert means to remove it from your changeset, so only files actually changed will be checked out.